# How can i get rows to display in smarty php?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have a php mysql smarty site where I want to display rows for sql table. I can't get php to compile correctly. "Message:  MySQL Query fail: Resource id #20" and "MySQL Error:    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1"  I know the database connectes because if I remove this section of code my page works and connects to a single line that is needed.

Any Help Appreciated

```
$db->connect();

$sql_detail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `details` WHERE part='158'");

$rows = $db->query($sql_detail);

$smarty->assign('results', $db->fetch_all_array($rows));
```

I am using the PHP MYSQL wrapper at http://www.ricocheting.com/code/php/mysql-database-class-wrapper

for smarty I am wanting something to this effect:

```
{foreach from=$myArray key=k item=v}
   <li>{$k}: {$v}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Change your $sql_detail to this: `$sql_detail = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE part='158'";` Still the same error?

Comment: That got rid of the first error. I didn't notice I was querying twice. The "MySQL Query fail: Resource id #20" is still present

Comment: now try this: `$smarty->assign('results', $db->fetch_all_array($sql_detail));`

Comment: Ok. I now get "0: 
Notice: Array to string conversion in mylocalfolder/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(171) : eval()'d code on line 102
Array"

Answer (score 0):

By the error message your error seems to be here:

```
$sql_detail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `details` WHERE part='158'");
```

Make sure you have selected the correct database name using mysql_select_db or something similar. Also make sure details is a table and that there is a column named part.

PS: mysql extension is deprecated you should use mysqli or other extensions that are still being maintained